# Google Spreadsheets not loading

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Google Spreadsheets with a lot of very important data and some scripts that were working well. At some point, the browser crashed and I reloaded the page. After that, I can't access that (only that!) spreadsheet any more! I tried from other Google accounts but it doesn't work. All I get is the "Loading..." message in the browser tab and nothing more (the loading process never completes). 
I also can't copy the file or download it! Ie, I can lose all the information in my spreadsheet and also lose all my scripts! (I never think something like this could happen with a Google Product).

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Have you cleared your browser's cache yet?

Comment: Unless you have a backup up the docmument you might be out of luck sounds like something cause the file to become corrupt.

Answer (score 1):

"Have you cleared your browser's cache yet?" sgtbeano - Yes, it fixed the problem!

Comment: Good to read that did the trick, will keep that in mind.